# How to find date lies in which week of month

Tags: java-8

Suppose I have a date in year-month-day format. Say "2015-02-12". Now I want to find that in which week this date lies. I mean 12 lies in 2nd week of Funerary. I want if I fo something like

LocalDate date =  2015-02-12;

date.getWeekOfMoth should gives me 2 because 2 lies in 2nd week of February. How can i do it ?

Thanks

### Edit

Hi, I am so sorry. I should replied you before you asked. I tried with the following code

```
String input = "2015-01-31";

SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("w");
Date date = df.parse(input);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println(week);
```

It prints `2`.

While when I check with the following code

```
String valuee="2015-01-31";
Date currentDate =new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(valuee);

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("w").format(currentDate));
```

It prints `5`.

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Remember to feed it with your date format and string with this date as input.

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
Date date = df.parse(input);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: Sorry again for not reply you. Kindly check my edit in the question. I didn't add code to your comment. The code you provided print `2`. Actually I changed the logic, first I was trying to do with the week of month, but then I decided to do with week of year. But `2015-01-31` do not come in `2nd week of month`. So as I changed the logic so I couldn't check it further.